# Iterate array of objects inside node using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, instagram

I use this function to read the contents of Instagram JSON files and save the information in a dictionary. I have the following question: How can I iterate the array of objects within ['node']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges']? This is my code:

```
info = {}

def store_data(file):

    with open(file) as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        try:
            info["tagged_users"] = data['node']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges'][0]['node']['user']['username']
        except KeyError:
            info["tagged_users"] = "null"
        return info
```

As you can see in the image below, there are 12 objects in the array, my code only works for the first one [0]. I need to get the username of each one.

[Array example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIpYf.png)

Basically:

```
data['node']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges'][0]['node']['user']['username']
data['node']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges'][1]['node']['user']['username']
data['node']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges'][2]['node']['user']['username']
data['node']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges'][3]['node']['user']['username']
...
data['node']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges'][x]['node']['user']['username']
```

Comment: It's quite difficult to figure out the problem of your codes without all the details of the objects? Maybe you can check the variable after json.load to see whether the fields match your line of code.

Comment: I modified the question to make it clearer, plus I attached an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, your code works only for one edge - that's that you asked for

under `data['node']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges']` is a list of dictionaries.

to iterate over list you simply use for loop

```
for each_edge in data['node']['edge_media_to_tagged_user']['edges']:
    print(each_edge) # or whatever you wish to do here
```